# GitBash error: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: bash, github, git-bash

I'm trying to push a dataset of images and masks to the master branch of my GitHub repo and it keeps not working and giving me the below error messages. The size of the dataset is around 5GB. I just want to upload this dataset onto my GitHub repo and was told that bash was the best way to do it, does anyone know how to fix this error, or any other methods I could use to upload my dataset to GitHub?

Edit: Printed error message in text rather than as an image

Error message:

```
$ git push origin master 
Enumerating objects: 1025, done. 
Counting objects: 100% (1025/1025), done. 
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1020/1020), done. 
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) 
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet 
Writing objects: 100% (1020/1020), 3.02 GiB | 16.00 MiB/s, done. 
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly 
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: please include the error as text!

Comment: @ti7 I've added the error message as text, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet)