# Error installing Homebrew "unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet"

Tags: macos, homebrew

I tried installing Homebrew on the M1 Mac Mini using the command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

as it is on the docs.

Then mid-way got this error

```
==> Tapping homebrew/core
remote: Enumerating objects: 1107077, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (228/228), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (157/157), done.
error: 545 bytes of body are still expected.44 MiB | 341.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch --force origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
myuser~ %
```

Comment: add github tag (as this is more github related)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is more of github checkout issue rather than Homebrew issue, checkout [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69891948/791609):

> It might be your network issue. If the network is too slow, then it might disconnect connection unexpectedly.
>
> If you are having a good internet and still getting this message then it might be an issue with post buffer. You can resolve it by executing the following command in your cmd.
>
> `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`

Comment: It worked for me with slight change

`git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000`

Comment: Using the postBuffer value suggested by @PratikKate also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing http.postBuffer didn't work for me (on M1 Mac), but disabling HTTP/2 and using HTTP/1.1 did:

`git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1`