# Failed to publish branch to remote Github repository

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, git-clone, github-desktop

I am using Github desktop as an interface and I am trying to push an initialized repository onto GitHub. I actually created the repo on GitHub and cloned it into my local machine and thus is where i made changes.

however even after my changes; I cannot push the changes I have committed towards the remote GitHub repo.

[Error message displayed by Github desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8fec.png)

I have tried using the command `git push -u origin main` to push changes through the terminal and it still gives me an error displayed below.

```
Enumerating objects: 885, done.
Counting objects: 100% (885/885), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (844/844), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (885/885), 151.08 MiB | 5.03 MiB/s, done.
Total 885 (delta 168), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I need help to see what I am missing; pointers are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet)

Comment: @JensSchauder thanks for the suggestion; I read through the question and tried the answers for the windows machine unfortunately it still failed. We are back to square one

Comment: Have you tried changing the http version to use v1 instead: `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1` If you want to revert to the default, you can just run the same command replacing 1.1 with 2

Comment: I had to refactor the entire codebase; I realised the issue was due to many factors; poor network connection, node module files hadn’t been ignored and then I had also generated a Personal Access Token that needed to be input. I decided to clone the repo afresh from GitHub, applied the changes and when I pushed this time; it was successful.