# Getting Fatal error while cloning git repo

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

So im getting this error in SourceTree while i was trying to clone the git repo.

```
error: 1462 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I did try the following code given in this link([Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet) "Link") via Git bash.

```
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

git config --global core.compression 0
git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI>
# cd to your newly created directory
git fetch --unshallow 
git pull --all
```

I was able to get the whole repo successfully. But not able to navigate to the SourceTree application itself.

Before while working on Sourcetree i didn't encounter this kind of error . I guess this start to happen only when i change the password. I did refresh my new password in Sourcetree. Still no luck.

I'm expecting this kind of window , after cloning.
[after cloning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb9sD.png) [before cloning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnbHe.png)

[image: Sourcetree error]
So i did try adding my cloned repo master branch to Sourcetree i was able to add successfully. But im not able to get other branches . I'm getting an error in the Remote Icon which is marked in topmost right red box. Attached a image above for reference. When i click it . It takes me to my Bitbucket chrome web page. Not sure what to do next!

Needs some help  :-)
Thanks

Comment: Do not use images of text: cut and paste the actual error message. See [ask].

Comment: How about now is it ok? @torek

Comment: Definitely better. I'm a bit confused as to what's still not working though - you say that Git is working now? The error message you've seen, and the sequence of shallow-clone then `git fetch --unshallow` is a workaround for, the case when your network is unreliable. That's not something Git can really do anything about. Once you have the clone you should be able to work normally, though.

Comment: I have attached an image (before cloning and after cloning).
the image in (before cloning) I use to get the error once i click clone. that's the error message I attached above. 
And i wanted it to the same window in which i attached image (after cloning).

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. If the clone completed successfully there is no problem left. Sourcetree could not do the clone but the command line could. Good! Problem solved.

Comment: ok. i have the repo now. how do I add it to my SourceTree and checkout other branch if needed?

Comment: So i did try adding my cloned repo master branch to Sourcetree i was able to add successfully.
But im not able to get other branches . I'm getting an error in the Remote Icon which is marked in topmost right red box. Attached a image above for reference.
When i click it . It takes me to my Bitbucket chrome web page. 
Not sure what to do next!

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error once during cloning a git repository and once during pod installation. Running the below command fixed it

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1024M
```

If it doesn't work follow the steps mentioned below.

> Try changing your network, use VPN or switch to the cellular data.