# Show filenames with Git pull as I am pulling?

Tags: git, github

I am currently in a mess where there I believe there is a big binary file being rate-limited by Github but I can't really see which file it is. Is there a way to run git pull so that it shows the file it is pulling as it progresses? Instead of just a count:

```
Receiving objects: 36% (67/183), 668.00 KiB | 7.00 KiB/s
```

**UPDATE**

I got a bit more verbosity by following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet). By doing this:

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

But it still doesn't show the file currently being downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Git transfers objects. They are not the checked-out files we see in a repository. So the fetch/push progress does not print what files it transfers. The file contents are stored in blobs. A blob that maps to a big binary is also big. To find out the big blobs,  we can use

```
git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects | grep blob | sort -n -k3
```

The `git cat-file` and `grep` list the blobs with sha1 values and sizes in bytes. The `sort` sorts them in ascending order. The large ones lay in the tail.

```
cb7e08a255a217dffa8f317179a7596b52488e15 blob 223996333
22491bcece9c1d3f7b4b9e07b9b14ab2740d3756 blob 224114333
c6d26a1f8394881824cae82174008b34720beb5d blob 225221333
```

To find which commit introduces the big blobs, taking `c6d26a1f8394881824cae82174008b34720beb5d` for example, we can try

```
git log --all --find-object=c6d26a1f8394881824cae82174008b34720beb5d
```

It prints the commit. Sometimes it prints nothing. Suppose the commit is `abc123`. To find the file that maps to the blob,

```
git ls-tree -r abc123 | grep c6d26a1f8394881824cae82174008b34720beb5d
```

It prints the sha1 value and the file path.

This method inspects the blobs in the whole history. We could also focus on a commit, for example the head of a branch. First, checkout the commit or the branch,

```
git checkout foo
```

Then check if `globstar` is on,

```
shopt | grep globstar
```

If it prints off, then use `shopt -s globstar` to enable it. And the final step,

```
du -s **/*.* | sort -n -k1
```

It prints the size and path of each checked-out file in ascending order. Note that if a file does not have an extension, it is not included in the output.

With the paths and sizes, you could find out the big binaries.

Comment: As an alternative to the trick with glob options, you could use `find` to list only files, and exclude the `.git` directory specifically: `find . -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -exec du '{}' ';'`

Comment: @IMSoP Great! Thanks for the method. It can list the file without an extension.

Comment: Note that a very large blob *might*, if it compresses well, be transferred as a very small deltified object in a pack file. Of course this isn't the situation the OP expects here.