# Git sometimes won't push when I'm connected to (Proton) VPN

Tags: git

For the last few years I've been using a Mac + VPN when doing dev work. I've always been able to `git push` without any issues.

I recently switched to Windows (for my sins) and use WSL for dev. Often `git push` errors out when connected to my VPN. Sometimes it works though.

Any idea why this *sometimes* happens?

```
# With Proton VPN
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 1.13 KiB | 10.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

# Without Proton VPN
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 1.13 KiB | 12.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.
To https://github.com/codeananda/breakout_detector.git
   f03e07d..bcffddf  non_parallel_report -> non_parallel_report
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet)

Comment: It's *some* kind of networking issue. Exactly what is hard to say without having your system and instrumenting it. I'd bet on a driver bug in WSL, especially since there are known ones that do this.