# GitHub or Git is throwing: message authentication code incorrect

Tags: git, github

Command:

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:apache/ofbiz-framework.git && \                                                                                    
git submodule update --remote && \
git add . && \
git commit -m "Updated the submodules" && \
git push
Cloning into 'ofbiz-framework'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 458146, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1320/1320), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (595/595), done.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 140.82.112.4 port 22: message authentication code incorrect
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I am able to clone my projects in my repos on GitHub but for some reason I cannot pull ofbiz from GitHub.

So why am I getting this error?

Details:

```
lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                   
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.4
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

Git:

```
git version 2.35.1
```

Comment: Idk it's ZSH or Kali printing it.

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet

Comment: @matt it is different. The other post does not have this in the error: `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 140.82.112.4 port 22: message authentication code incorrect`

Comment: I tried this `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400` did not change anything. And like I said in the question I was able to clone a repo directly... It is only the **git modules** causing issues.

Comment: I suggest running one command at a time rather than chaining them all together with `&&`. This will allow you to see which command causes the error.

Comment: Note that Git doesn't "do" authentication itself. It has some minimal support so that other programs can do it. Any time you get authentication errors, it's *almost* always the other program(s) involved. The main exception is when it's a matter of configuring the right authentication program for Git to run for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing comes from OpenSSH.  When you use SSH, the connection is protected from tampering using a message authentication code (a MAC) or an authenticated cipher (an AEAD).  Any modification to the message data, whether intentional or unintentional, will result in the MAC failing to verify with near certainty.  This is always fatal because it's a security measure and otherwise tampering with the data would be possible.

Ultimately, all this tells you is that something happened to the data in the connection.  That could be a network problem on your machine or with your network card, router, Wi-Fi infrastructure, or your ISP.  It could be intentional tampering or censorship.  It can be due to an antivirus, firewall, or any sort of proxy, which is mostly a problem on Windows.  All we know is that the data that GitHub sent isn't what you received and so the connection was dropped.  It's up to you to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: As a side note here, a bunch of people have reported various bugs in various Ethernet drivers, especially when using TCP offload. People are always looking to offload the end-to-end checking from the host CPU, and thereby introducing errors like this that are only caught when something else (e.g., ssh) does its own end-to-end checking...

Comment: So the issue was the USB wifi key (or whatever it is called). I connected my computer with the Ethernet cable and it worked. It's weird because I have never had any issues before with internet access and browsing the web.