# Is there a way to resolve this Github error when pushing work

Tags: git, github, repository, config, fatal-error

I am using this command to push work to my github:

```
git push -u origin main
```

I keep getting this error:

[image: the error message]

> error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I tried increased the size of  Git's HTTP buffer using:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But I still get the same error message, nothing changes. I even tried to create a new repo - same thing, I can't push any work to the new repo.

Comment: [The Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) mentions that you should not need to change `http.postBuffer` and setting it only serves to waste lots of memory in all but the most unusual situations.  It almost certainly won't help your problem.

Comment: There seems to be some suggestions here: [code-example-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet](https://akashmittal.com/code-example-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet/) and a boatload of things people have tried here: [github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet) If you are using http I think if I were you I would try switching to ssh (or vice versa) first and see if you have better luck.

Comment: I tried switching to ssh but because it is Windows so PowerShell it cant work with eval $(ssh-agent -s)

Comment: follow the windows instructions for ssh if you are using powershell: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent (it is not the same as for linux or gitbash). I don't know why it isn't mentioned and maybe its not necessary but always make sure the SSH service mentioned is set to start automatically (delayed start) in my services, if it is not (i.e., if it is set to manual start).

Comment: ... or, instead install and use gitbash / git for windows