# Git Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length 196 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Tags: git, github

Please i keep getting this error on my terminal. I have no idea what it means even though I have tried different solutions and none has worked

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 196
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.git'
```

I first thought it was a bad internet connection but right now I am almost certain it is not as I have tried several providers and servers and even monitored download and upload speed.

can someone please explain what this is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet)

Comment: it doesn't answer the question @zac Anger

Answer (score 0):

The message “fatal: protocol error: bad line length 196” means that part of the data in the protocol has been corrupted.  Git's HTTP protocol uses a pkt-line format, which consists of 4 hex bytes that specify a length, and then the remainder of the data.  In this case, the line length is not correct.

There are a couple things that could theoretically be happening.  First, it's possible GitHub has a problem and is sending invalid data.  This is very unlikely, since someone would have noticed right away.  It's also possible that your version of Git has a problem, which is also pretty unlikely.

Because you're using HTTPS, there's integrity checking from end to end for the data, so the data can't be tampered with unless you've specifically allowed that.  If it were a network problem, the TLS connection would fail, and you'd see a totally different error.  Thus, the most likely answer for this is that you have some software on your machine or on your network that is set up to transparently intercept encrypted connections.  That could be an antivirus or firewall other than the default (extremely common on Windows), monitoring software on your system, parental controls, or a TLS MITM proxy on your network (if you're in a corporate environment or school).  All of these are known generally as proxies, and many varieties of proxies are known to cause this problem.

If you have such software, you should simply uninstall it completely and reboot (disabling it is often insufficient), or move to a network without the proxy.  If this is a corporate environment where that's not possible, complain to your IT department.

It may also happen to work to switch to SSH.  Sometimes this sort of proxy doesn't understand SSH, and if you use SSH [*and verify GitHub's SSH fingerprint correctly*](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints), then it may be possible to avoid the tampering which is breaking your connection.

Comment: i have been unable to figure what the issue might be. but I was able to create another user on my windows and I got to work on it. I'll be more than happy if someone can actually help resolve it cos its rally difficult having to switch between users on my window