While cloning the git repository getting unexpected disconnect while reading side band packet
Cloning into 'repo?'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2521, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2521/2521), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2273/2273), done.
error: 4318 bytes of body are still expectediB | 361.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I try the this command git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI> but it also didn't work at all.

similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366582/github-unexpected-disconnect-while-reading-sideband-packet

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Set the HTTP Post buffer to a higher value: git config http.postBuffer 10g
